# how to import other schema jars when using the scomp tool

Tags: java, xmlbeans

there is a huge amount of xml schemas for the business, some of them are common types like Money.xsd, Address.xsd, etc, while others are business specific like Customer.xsd, ShippingOrder.xsd, etc. So I decide to compile these schemas into 2 jars, one is commonbeans.jar, the other is businessbeans.jar.

I've separated them into different folders.

to build the commonbeans.jar is simple, just run "scomp -out commonbeans.jar ....\common*.xsd";

while run "scomp -out businessbeans.jar ....\business*.xsd" is a different story, there are errors say can't find those common types, and run "scomp -out businessbeans.jar ....\business*.xsd ....\business*.xsd" will blindly duplicate all the common types into the businessbeans.jar.

so is there any way to link the commonbeans.jar when compile those busimess schemas, maybe something like "scomp -out businessbeans.jar ....\business*.xsd commonbeans.jar".

I hope my poor english has expressed my issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `-cp` argument.

```
scomp -cp s1.jar -out s2.jar s2.xsd
```

See [XmlBeansFaq](http://wiki.apache.org/xmlbeans/XmlBeansFaq#schemaDependencies) for more details.